# how to display the listbox items to a label using VB2008

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display listbox items in a label.
After debugging,I get the error : " make sure that the maximun index on the list is less than the list size"

any comment will be  highly appreciate,

```
Private Sub xMultiButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles xMultiButton.Click

    Dim count As Integer
    count = Me.xNamesListBox.Items.Count
    For count = 0 To 3
        Me.xResultLabel.Text = Me.xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Item(0).ToString & ControlChars.NewLine _
            & Me.xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Item(1).ToString & ControlChars.NewLine _
            & Me.xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Item(2).ToString & ControlChars.NewLine _
            & Me.xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Item(3).ToString & ControlChars.NewLine _
            & Me.xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Item(4).ToString


    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **For Each** for display all selected items of a listbox

```
    For Each Str As String In xNamesListBox.SelectedItems
        xResultLabel.Text += Str & Environment.NewLine
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
For i As Int16 = 0 To xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1
    xResultLabel.Text += xNamesListBox.SelectedItems.Item(i).ToString() & ControlChars.NewLine
Next
```

Comment: It worked perfect using only Integer as datatype...Thanks very much.